# how to make a discord bot deleting my cmd after replying to it like :

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

1. how to make a discord bot deleting my command after replying to it, like:

```
@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')
```

2. the bot has to remove my message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will listen for messages and if the content of the message is "ping" it will respond with "Pong!" and then delete the users "ping" message.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
    msg.delete();
  }
});
```